# 「Aの運営は，Bとの連携のもと，C業務を遂行する。」の解析

Tags: grammar, translation

I am having issues translating 「Aの運営は，Bとの連携のもと，C業務を遂行する。」

Edit: Here's the sentence in its original form.

災害対策部局本部の運営は，災害対策本部との連携のもと，災害対策業務を遂行する。

Is this grammar even technically correct? 
It feels like the sentence should at least end with 「～ものとする。」
The middle part is fine, but it's the first and last chunks I'm having trouble connecting.

The best I could come up with is "**A** shall conduct **C** affairs in coordination with **B**.", but then I end up not using the word 「運営」 at all, which I'd like to avoid as my boss insists on word-for-word translation.

Any ideas would help. Thanks in advance!

Edit: My apologies, I should have been more clear. **A** and **B** are names of organizations.

Edit: I ended up going with the translation of "The Departmental Disaster Response Headquarters shall, in coordination with the Disaster Response Headquarters, conduct disaster response affairs." for the time being.

Comment: You would need to tell us what kind of word, if not exactly what word, A is.  B and C are pretty straightforward as they are.

Comment: My apologies. A and B are names of organizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Japanese sentence sounds a little bit weird, as described in the answer by Yuuichi Tam.

If 「運営」 were 「運営者」 the sentence would make sense, with a natural meaning "the operator of **A** conduct **C** affairs, in coordination with **B**."
Actually 「運営」 can mean 「運営者」 in a slangy context, but your sentence should not fit this case, as it seems to be in a rigid context.

---

Another possibility is that 「**A**の運営は」 is meant to be "with regard to the operation of **A**".
In this case, 「は」 is a topic marker but doesn't mark a subject.
Here the subject of your sentence is not clarified. I'm not sure what it is, as an enough context is not provided.

Now the translation would be:

> (Someone) conduct **C** affairs in coordination with **B**, *for the sake of the operation of **A***.

The blank (someone) is not clear but it might be "we".

Note that this is just a possibility.
If you could provide more context, there would be a more credible answer.

---

**Edit**: Thank you for providing more context.
Unfortunately the original sentence doesn't seem perfectly natural, but I can proceed a bit more.

A clearer and equivalent sentence would be:

> 災害対策部局本部の運営**にあたって**は，災害対策本部との連携のもと，災害対策業務を遂行する。

As for the last part, the usage of 「遂行する」 is at least grammatical.
Consider the last part 「災害対策業務を遂行する」, it is simply 「OをVする」 form, which is of course grammatical. The original sentence is obtained by adding some modification to that.

Also, you already have got "conduct" for the translation of 「遂行する」, which fits the sentence well.
It may be a little confusing because the sentence doesn't have explicit subject.
The presence of absence of 「ものとする」 doesn't matter in the grammatical point of view.

Comment: Yes, with formal documents like this, the phrase "~の運営は" often carries the connotation that you pointed out, so I went with that interpretation. I just couldn't see how that last "遂行する" would fit in, at least grammatically. I ended up going with "The Departmental Disaster Response Headquarters shall, in coordination with the Disaster Response Headquarters, conduct disaster response affairs." because I have other things to do and I couldn't be stuck on this one sentence.

Comment: The last chunk in itself makes perfect sense, as you mentioned. I just couldn't wrap my head around 「災害対策部局本部の運営は...災害対策業務を遂行する。」If I had a 「ものとする」 at the end there, it would have made it clear that 「運営」 wouldn't be 「遂行する」 the 「業務」, but that the clause is simply stipulating the duties to be carried out in regards to the operations of the organization. Or, as you put it, 「にあたって」 would have worked perfectly. Unfortunately, nobody wants to go through the whole deliberation process involving dozens of lawyers, executives, and trustees again so the Japanese will stay as is. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your Japanese sentence is translated as "the conduct of A execute C in cooperation with B" and this is unnatural because conduct(運営) can't execute C because 運営 means "to run organizations". However if it is Aの運営者, it would make sense because Aの運営者(the operator of A) can execute C.

Aは，Bとの連携のもと，C業務を遂行する make sense and if you put 遂行する into 行う,it would be easily to understand.

Your English sentence "A shall conduct C affairs in coordination with B." is translated as Aは、Bと連携してC業務を行う(管理する)だろう.

Comment: The issue with 遂行する that you mention is exactly the problem I was having. "Aの運営" would simply be "The management of A", but that last part completely threw me off because as you said, an act engaging in an act is not possible. I ended up ignoring the seemingly incorrect grammar and went with the original intent of the clause.

On a side note, the use of "shall" in writing like this is more like "~ものとする" rather than "だろう".